# Java JPA (EclipseLink) How to receive the next GeneratedValue before persisting actual entity?

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, auto-increment, auto-generate

I'm using the EclipseLink implementation of JPA and I've got a problem.

Here is my entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "attendances")
public class Attendance implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Short id;
```

`....`

In my MySQL table (that is the underlying data store) I have `auto_increment` flag also set.

**How can I get the auto-generated value (`id` field) before persisting the entity?** So if there are 3 entities in the table (`id IN (1, 2, 3)`), I want to get 4 as the next auto-generated value.

The only workaround I have is:

1. Get the id of the entity with the largest `id` field.

Is that all I can do?

Comment: Why would you like to do that?

Comment: @Nizet I have a dialog for creating an attendance and i want the user to know the id of the attendance that is about to be created. That's not 100% needed by it's said to be helpful.

Comment: @JB Nizet: A very valid question, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, if using JPA 2.0,

```
entityManagerFactory.getPersistenceUnitUtil().getIdentifier(attendance);
```

**DISCLAIMER:** *Never tried it myself.*

Otherwise, you can change your id generation strategy to something, that can get you the `id` before persisting the entity. For example, try to use table generator to generate your `id`s. Here, I found an example, [Use Table Generator To Generate ID](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JPA/UseTableGeneratorToGenerateID.htm). Then you would be able to read the value from that table, directly. You may not be able to handle this automatically using `@Id`, precisely you will end up calculating the next `id` yourself. Hence, you can employ the same idea but do all the work yourself and set the `id` while creating the operation, and don't let JPA to generate one.

Or you might like to use the `sequence`, if supported. In case of `sequence` also you need to get the next value yourself and set it manually. Be prepared to loose skipped `id`s in case of no insert, or handle that somehow.

Or you are fine with what you are doing. Just take care of atomicity. Or you may not have the case of multiple transactions running simultaneously.

Comment: The getIdentifier call can't work. the documentation of the method says: "Return the id of the entity. A generated id is not guaranteed to be available until after the database insert has occurred. Returns null if the entity does not yet have an id. "

Comment: @JB Nizet: So should i rather use Table Generator?

Comment: @JB Nizet: O'yeah, no guarantee from me too. I mean, I never tried it, as I stated. BTW, no guarantee also infers that that it might work. Anyways, I have also given a second suggestion, OP might consider that.

Comment: @Daniel: Yes, by all means. But trying that once wouldn't hurt. Its simple, you see.

Comment: @Daniel: no. A TableGenerator won't let you know the ID before the persist, since it's persist which calls the generator to get an ID. You'll have to assign IDs by yourself.

Comment: @JB Nizet: Can't you query that id-table, as you do other entities?

Comment: You may use the same **strategy** as a table generator, but you'll have to query and update the table manually, and assign the ID manually. You will also have to handle conflicts between concurrent transactions by yourself, by generating the next ID or batch of IDs in a very short-lived transaction.

Comment: @JB Nizet: So the workaround i mentioned in the question is the easiest, yeah?

Comment: No. It won't work until you only have one transaction at a time. Suppose you have two transactions running at the same time. Both will query for the next value and both will display the same value to the user.

Comment: @JB Nizet: Yes, you can. Just take care of atomicity. Or you may not have the case of multiple transactions running simultaneously.

Comment: Taking care of atomicity, in this case, would mean forbidding any insert into the table until the user watching the dialog decides to persist or cancel. It's not doable.

Comment: @JB Nizet: Just insert a row and then delete it if nothing happens. You made the thing sound like impossible. If sequential thing is not needed UUID can be used. Or simple Time stamp might work. Where is the problem.